# Bar graph with tick labels from table column by index?

Tags: pgfplots

**How do I use `yticklabels from table` if I want to define the column by index?**

According to the documentation of `yticklabels from table`: `Furthermore, it can be [index] <integer> in which case <integer> is a column index.`But for some reason I can't get this to work. What am I missing here?

Below is a minimal example which gives an error on Overleaf:

`Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column '0' from table '<inline_table>'. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases).`

I'd like to get 4 horizontal bars with labels from the first column, length from the second column - and if there is no workaround, the third column is the order of the bars.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.15,
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
Mangos 200 4
Bananas 123 3
Apples 50 2
Oranges 8 1
}\loadedtable;

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        ytick=data,
        xmin=0,
        yticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{0}
    ]
        \addplot table [x index={1}, y index={2}] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual says

> ```
> Furthermore, it can be [index]⟨integer⟩ in which case ⟨integer⟩ is a column index.
> ```

which indeed works, i.e. you forgot `[index]`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.15,
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
Mangos 200 4
Bananas 123 3
Apples 50 2
Oranges 8 1
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        ytick=data,
        xmin=0,
        yticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{[index] 0}
    ]
        \addplot table [x index={1}, y index={2}] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(You do not need a semicolon after `\pgfplotstableread`.)

Comment: Ah, indeed! I totally didn't understand the syntax here. Thanks!